# ChatSecure-iOS, [Travis Detected] GPG verification disabled - Compiling for i386 only

Tags: ios, build, ios-simulator, chat, x86-64

I am working on Open Source ChatSecure (iOS). (https://chatsecure.org/developers/)
But while creating build I am getting error **"missing required architecture x86_64 in file"**. 
 This error occurs only if I am using **64-bit architecture simulator**, Its working fine with other simulators.

In log I have checked that errors are because of these three libraries (`libotr.a`, `libgcrypt.a`, `libgpg-error.a`) which are part of [OTRKit](https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit) (Submodule of [ChatSecure-iOS](https://github.com/chrisballinger/ChatSecure-iOS)). These libraries are not building properly which compatibles with **x86_64 architecture**. 
For building those libraries I have followed following steps,

1) `$ git submodule add https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit.git Submodules/OTRKit` (added OTRKit as a Submodule in ChatSecure app) 
2) `$ bash build-libgpg-error.sh` 
3) `$ bash build-libgcrypt.sh` 
4) `$ bash build-libotr.sh` 

Following log is generated while building `libgpg-error.a`,

```
xxx-Mac-Minixxx:OTRKit xxx$ bash build-libgpg-error.sh
Building libgpg-error...
[Travis Detected] GPG verification disabled - Compiling for i386 only
Downloading libgpg-error-1.12.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  477k  100  477k    0     0  13777      0  0:00:35  0:00:35 --:--:-- 19253
Building without ccache
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for i386-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin
configure: autobuild project... libgpg-error
configure: autobuild revision... 1.12
configure: autobuild hostname... xxx-Mac-Minixxx.local
configure: autobuild timestamp... 20140830-194606
checking for i386-apple-darwin-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gawk... (cached) awk
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-dumpbin... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-link... no
checking for dumpbin... no
checking for link... link -dump
checking the name lister (nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 file names to i386-apple-darwin format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for i386-apple-darwin-objdump... no
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for i386-apple-darwin-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-strip... strip
checking for i386-apple-darwin-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
checking for i386-apple-darwin-mt... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin-dsymutil... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for i386-apple-darwin-nmedit... no
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for i386-apple-darwin-lipo... no
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for i386-apple-darwin-otool... no
checking for otool... otool
checking for i386-apple-darwin-otool64... no
checking for otool64... no
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for i386-apple-darwin-windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for cc for build... gcc
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... :
checking for xgettext... no
checking for msgmerge... no
checking for ld used by GCC... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... yes
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... yes
checking for GNU gettext in libc... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
checking how to link with libiconv... -liconv
checking for GNU gettext in libintl... no
checking whether to use NLS... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking whether strerror_r is declared... yes
checking for strerror_r... yes
checking whether strerror_r returns char *... no
checking for strerror_r... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/gpg-error-config
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing po-directories commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile

        libgpg-error-1.12 prepared for make

        Revision: 12243ce  (4644)
        Platform: i386-apple-darwin


make  all-recursive
Making all in m4
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
awk -f ./mkerrnos.awk ./errnos.in >code-to-errno.h
awk -f ./mkerrcodes1.awk ./errnos.in >_mkerrcodes.h
gcc -E   _mkerrcodes.h | grep GPG_ERR_ | \
               awk -f ./mkerrcodes.awk >mkerrcodes.h
awk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        ./err-sources.h.in >err-sources-sym.h
awk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        ./err-codes.h.in >err-codes-sym.h
awk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        -v prefix=GPG_ERR_ -v namespace=errnos_ \
        ./errnos.in >errnos-sym.h
rm extra-h.in
rm: extra-h.in: No such file or directory
make[2]: [extra-h.in] Error 1 (ignored)
echo "/* The version string of this header. */" >>extra-h.in
rm _mkerrcodes.h
echo "#define GPG_ERROR_VERSION \"1.12\"" >>extra-h.in
cat ./gpg-error.def.in >_gpg-error.def.h
echo >>extra-h.in
echo "/* The version number of this header. */" >>extra-h.in
gcc -E -I. -I..   _gpg-error.def.h | \
      grep -v '^#' >gpg-error.def
echo "#define GPG_ERROR_VERSION_NUMBER 0x010c00" >>extra-h.in
echo >>extra-h.in
echo EOF >>extra-h.in
echo "/*dummy*/" > mkw32errmap.map.c
gcc -I. -I. -o mkerrcodes ./mkerrcodes.c
rm _gpg-error.def.h
awk -f ./mkheader.awk \
        ./err-sources.h.in \
        ./err-codes.h.in \
        ./errnos.in \
        extra-h.in \
        ./gpg-error.h.in > gpg-error.h
./mkerrcodes | awk -f ./mkerrcodes2.awk >code-from-errno.h
make  all-am
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-init.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-init.lo `test -f 'init.c' || echo './'`init.c
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-version.lo `test -f 'version.c' || echo './'`version.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo -c version.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-version.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-init.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo -c init.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-init.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Plo
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo `test -f 'strsource.c' || echo './'`strsource.c
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo `test -f 'strerror.c' || echo './'`strerror.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo -c strsource.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-strsource.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo -c strerror.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-strerror.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo `test -f 'code-to-errno.c' || echo './'`code-to-errno.c
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo `test -f 'code-from-errno.c' || echo './'`code-from-errno.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo -c code-to-errno.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\" -g -arch i386 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo -c code-from-errno.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Plo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT gpg_error-strsource-sym.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-strsource-sym.o `test -f 'strsource-sym.c' || echo './'`strsource-sym.c
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Plo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT gpg_error-strerror-sym.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-strerror-sym.o `test -f 'strerror-sym.c' || echo './'`strerror-sym.c
mv -f .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Tpo .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/locale\"    -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT gpg_error-gpg-error.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-gpg-error.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-gpg-error.o `test -f 'gpg-error.c' || echo './'`gpg-error.c
mv -f .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Tpo .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -version-info 10:0:10   -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -L/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/lib -o libgpg-error.la -rpath /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib  libgpg_error_la-init.lo libgpg_error_la-version.lo libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo   
t-version.c:86:42: warning: data argument not used by format string
      [-Wformat-extra-args]
               " for a newer version\n", logpfx);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
1 warning generated.
mv -f .deps/t-version.Tpo .deps/t-version.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src     -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -MT t-syserror.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/t-syserror.Tpo -c -o t-syserror.o t-syserror.c
mv -f .deps/t-strerror.Tpo .deps/t-strerror.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk  -arch i386 -fPIE -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -L/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/dependencies/lib -o t-syserror t-syserror.o ../src/libgpg-error.la 
make  install-am
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libgpg-error.la '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgpg-error.lai /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib/libgpg-error.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgpg-error.a /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib/libgpg-error.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib/libgpg-error.a
libtool: install: ranlib /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/lib/libgpg-error.a
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/bin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c gpg-error '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c gpg-error /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/bin/gpg-error
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c gpg-error-config '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/bin'
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gpg-error.h '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/include'
 .././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/aclocal'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gpg-error.m4 '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/aclocal'
Making install in tests
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in po
if test "libgpg-error" = "gettext-tools"; then \
      .././install-sh -c -d /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/gettext/po; \
      for file in Makefile.in.in remove-potcdate.sin quot.sed boldquot.sed en@quot.header en@boldquot.header insert-header.sin Rules-quot   Makevars.template; do \
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$file \
                /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/gettext/po/$file; \
      done; \
      for file in Makevars; do \
        rm -f /Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/gettext/po/$file; \
      done; \
    else \
      : ; \
    fi
Making install in lang
Making install in cl
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gpg-error.asd gpg-error-package.lisp gpg-error.lisp '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error'
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gpg-error-codes.lisp '/Users/xxx/Desktop/ChatSecure-iOS/27-08-2014/ChatSecure-iOS/Submodules/OTRKit/build/built/iPhoneSimulator7.1-i386.sdk/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error'
Making clean in tests
rm -rf .libs _libs
 rm -f t-version t-strerror t-syserror
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.lo
Making clean in src
 rm -f gpg-error
test -z "err-sources.h err-codes.h code-to-errno.h code-from-errno.h gpg-error.h mkerrcodes mkerrcodes.h gpg-error.def mkw32errmap.tab.h mkw32errmap.map.c err-sources-sym.h err-codes-sym.h errnos-sym.h gpg-extra/errno.h extra-h.in _mkerrcodes.h _gpg-error.def.h mkw32errmap.tab.h mkw32errmap.map.c" || rm -f err-sources.h err-codes.h code-to-errno.h code-from-errno.h gpg-error.h mkerrcodes mkerrcodes.h gpg-error.def mkw32errmap.tab.h mkw32errmap.map.c err-sources-sym.h err-codes-sym.h errnos-sym.h gpg-extra/errno.h extra-h.in _mkerrcodes.h _gpg-error.def.h mkw32errmap.tab.h mkw32errmap.map.c
```

I have also post same issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit/issues/17) but didn't get any update. Hopefully expecting here.
 Thanks!

I am new in iOS development, Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a library, the library has to be built with the same architecture as the code you're linking it into. In this case, it looks like those three libraries (`libotr.a`, `libgcrypt.a`, `libgpg-error.a`) were built in 32 bit, so you can't link them into a 64 bit build.

You need to get the x86_64 builds of those three libraries. This might involve rebuilding them yourself. Ideally, you would get/rebuild them in "universal" format, which means the library would contain *both* architectures, so you can link the same files into both 32bit and 64bit builds.

---

Notice that the OTRKit build script output says:

> [Travis Detected] GPG verification disabled - Compiling for i386 only

i386 is the Intel 32bit architecture. The build script for OTR think's you're Travis, so you need to do `export TRAVIS=0` before you build, in order to get the x86_64 arch built.

Someone has already submitted the bug here: https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit/issues/15

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried this way but still getting same error. This three libraries are found in [OTRKit](https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit.git) which submodule of [ChatSecure-iOS](https://github.com/chrisballinger/ChatSecure-iOS). I have followed all the steps mentioned in its ReadMe file and recreated new libraries.

Comment: Tom.. I have edited my answer please check. I have followed the step as you told.

Comment: It's still building the 32bit libraries only. See the update.

Comment: If I does `export TRAVIS=0` then it gives error `build-libgpg-error.sh: line 44: 0: command not found
Downloading libgpg-error-1.12.tar.bz2
COULD NOT VERIFY PACKAGE SIGNATURE...`

Comment: @TomDalling i am facing same problem & TRAVIS=0 not works. Plz help me to figured out the issue. Thanks